# solve job scheduling with some restrictions by genetic algorithm

Tags: scheduling, genetic-algorithm

I'm a new to genetic algorithm

there are many resources teaching how to implement genetic algorithm

and many examples like using binary number or array as a sequence of gene, doing selection and crossover to get the next generation without showing any restriction on which solution in the next generation is invalid (only a fitness function to tell is that a good solution or not)

in job-scheduling problem, if there are some restriction like, "job2 cant be allocated until job1 is finished", how can I make sure the result after crossover or mutation of the initial random solution will not obey the above restriction?

for example,

M1[ |-----job1-----|  | ---- job3 ----|]
M2[ |----job4----|  |-------job2------|]
M3[ |--job5--||-----job6-----|         ]

here job2 is allocated after job1.

If I want to generate the next generation, how can i guarantee the job2 will be allocated after job1?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would value the restriction with the fitness function. A bad fitness value for the wrong order keeps the restriction.